# How best to validate a mobile phone number based on character length, starting with and numeric using PHP

Tags: php, validation

I have a mobile phone number field.

I am currently validating if empty:

```
<?php
   if ($_REQUEST['text_message'] && !@$_REQUEST['text_message_mobile']){
      $errors[] = "Please enter your mobile number for text messages";
   }
?>
```

I would like to add validation to check that the mobile number is 11 characters long and begins with 07.

An example accepted phone number would be 07123456789.

How best would I go about adding this validation using PHP?

Comment: delete that `@` and use `isset($_REQUEST['text_message_mobile'])` instead.

Comment: Replace the `!@$_REQUEST['..']` with `!isset($_REQUEST['...']`; looks and is cleaner this way.

Comment: use `strlen($_REQUEST['text_message_mobile'])==11`

Comment: also u can use `substr(text_message_mobile, 0, 2)=='07'`

Comment: i don't understand why are are their down votes what wrong is asked here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [type comparisions in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) to look at how `isset` and `empty` responds with the variables you use.

Use [strln to look at the length of the string](https://www.php.net/strlen), so you can know if the number is 11 characters long.

Use [is_numeric to check if the variable contains only numbers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php), so you can avoid inputs like "07dsajdlsajdks".

Use [substr to look at the first two characters of the string](http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php), so you can know if the number has 07 at the start.

This is how, more or less, should look at the end:

```
<?php
   if(!isset($_REQUEST['text_message']) || empty($_REQUEST['text_message'])) {
      //Here is null or undefined or an empty string
      $errors[] = "Please enter your mobile number for text messages";
   }

   if(!is_numeric($_REQUEST['text_message'])) {
      $errors[] = "Please provide a valid number";
   }

   if(strlen($_REQUEST['text_message']) !== 11) {
      //Here is not 11 characters long
      $errors[] = "Please provide 11 character number";   
   }

   if(substr($_REQUEST['text_message'], 0, 2) !== "07") {

      $errors[] = "Please provide number with 07 in the first two digits";   
   }   
   

   if(count($errors) > 0) {

      echo "Resolve this errors: ";
      print_r($errors);
   }
   else {
      echo "You did everything perfect";
   }
?>
```

Comment: This looks great, I'll give it a go and let you know how I get on.

Comment: This would allow `07abcdefghi`

Comment: ahh yes... forgot about the numerical validation. Hopefully there's a simple solution for this?

Comment: Edited with now the validation of numeric phone numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a regular expression:

```
$number = "0711111111111";
$pattern = "/^07[0-9]{9}$/";
echo preg_match($pattern, $number);
```

This expression will match any string starting with "07" and followed by exactly 9 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know PHP, but I can give a solution with HTML and JavaScript.

Here is demo code:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function validate()
        {
            var reg = new RegExp("^07[0-9]{9}$");
            var mobile = document.getElementById("t1").value;
            if(!reg.test(mobile))
            {
                alert("Invalid mobile number");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    Mobile:<input id ="t1" type="text" maxlength = "11" />
    <input type="button" value ="check" onclick="validate()" />
</body>

</html>
```

It uses a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and checks with the **test** function.